# Form not submitting after bootstrap confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, confirmation

Firstly I will apologise my knowledge of jquery/javascript is not very good so my mistake maybe very obvious to some but I am still learning so be gentle!

I have a form which allows the members to delete posts they have made from the database. The form works fine and using php deletes the data from the database as I want. I wanted to create a popup that gets the user to confirm thats what they would like to do. I don't want to use the bog standard browser specific onclick method I wanted something a bit more customisable. So I am trying to use bootbox, I currently have the confirmation box popping up onclick but when you select yes, nothing else happens. I suspect the result from the jquery is not firing the form but from what I have read my code for that part is good?

I have pasted below my php, jquery and html

PHP:

```
<?php
$deletepost = 'none';
$deleteposterror = 'none';

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

    $del_topic_id = $_POST['topic_id_value'];

    // sql to delete a record
    $pass_fail = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id ='$del_topic_id';";

    $pass_fail .= "DELETE FROM posts WHERE topic_id_post ='$del_topic_id'";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $pass_fail)) {

    $deletepost = 'show';

    }else{

    $deleteposterror = 'show';
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $pass_fail. "  . mysqli_error($conn);    

    }

}
?>
```

HTML & PHP in while loop:

```
<?php


            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_by = '".$id."' ORDER BY topic_date DESC ";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

            while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

            $topic_id = $row ['topic_id'];
            $topic_subject = $row ['topic_subject']; 
            ?>



            <div class='chat_post_titles' >
            <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-7 chat_post_text_align_left'>
            <a href="../Chat/post.php?topic_id=<?php echo $topic_id?>"><?php echo $topic_subject?>.</a>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-2 chat_post_text_align_right'>
            <?php
            $my_date = $row['topic_date'];
            $date = DATE("G:i:s d/m/Y",strtotime($my_date));
            ?>
            <div class='hide_text'>Post Date: </div>
            <?php echo $date?>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-2 chat_post_text_align_centre'>
            <div class='hide_text'>Delete Post: </div>

            <form method="post" class="delete_post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="topic_id_value" id="topic_id_value" value="<?php echo $topic_id?>">
            <button type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger buttonElement">Delete</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

JQUERY at bottom of page:

```
</body>
<?php include("../PHP/js.php"); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Members/updatedetails.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Members/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('form').on('click','button.buttonElement',function (e) {
    var form = $(this).closest('form'); // <-- add this

    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Are you sure you want to delete your post?", 
        title: "Delete Post",
        buttons: {
            cancel: { 
                label: "No", 
                className: "btn btn-default"
            },
            confirm: { 
                label: "Yes", 
                className: "btn btn-default"
            }
         },
         callback: function(result) {
             if(result == true) {
                 form.submit();
             }
         }
    });
 });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your callback function checks for the variable "result", but this variable isn't set anywhere as far as I can see. Make sure that your click on "Yes" sets result = true, then the submit function should be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion HappyAnt, but I have tried that and it still doesn’t work! I agree that it must be something to do with that but just not sure what

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(result) in your callback function ? It should work according to bootbox.js documentation.

Comment: I suggest trying what Ilker Kadir Ozturk commented. Either your result variable isn't evaluating to "true", or you have a problem with your form selector. Concerning the second possibility you could try to use the form's id as a selector instead of relying on jQuery finding the closest form in the first line of your onclick function. Try replacing the last line in your script with $("#delete").submit() and see what happens then.

Comment: So I tried what you said Ozturk and it outputs as true, so it is outputting as expected, but then I am not sure why in the if statement its not submitting then form as result is equal to true? thanks again for your helps guys. I have also tried your idea HappyAnt but no luck. I know this is going to be something easy!

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the button tag id instead of the form tag, which doesn't have an id. So what I suggested can't work. :/ But you could add a new id to your form and then try it again with the corresponding id as selector.

Comment: Now I tested your original script on my local server and it runs as expected (except I don't get the confirmation as popup because I was too lazy to add bootstrap css to my test page). I click delete, I confirm and the form submits.

Comment: Did it still ask you to confirm? As I know the script works when the pop up box doesn’t work but when it does nothing happens!

Comment: I added the CSS later and tried again, it was working just like before, but with the popup overlay.

Comment: Hi Ant, are you able to tell what versions of jquery, bootstrap and bootbox you tested this on. As I still can't get it to work, did you change the code at all from above? as this is driving me insane as it should work!

Comment: Latest version of each one. And I didn't change anything except deleting the PHP tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out why my code wasn't working in my php I was using
    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
but when using javascript `submit()` function this name attr is removed. So I used the name of the hidden input like so `if(isset($_POST['topic_id_value']))` and it worked as normal.

Still thanks to the guys that gave me advice